# Can not convert code to vb.net, help requested

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to convert the following code to vb.net but online converters return error.  Could any body help please?

```
JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller _ins = new JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller(
    "<Installation Display Name>", "localhost", 
    "<New database instance name>", "<new database name>", "<database password>", 
    "<database backup filename>");

if (_ins.IsDone == false) _ins.ShowDialog();
if (_ins.IsRestart == true)
{
    Application.Exit();
    this.Close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: What code did it generate, and what was that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth those code converters usually want you to have the code in a class, not just some code stub.

```
    Dim _ins as JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller = New JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller("<Installation Display Name>", "localhost", "<New database instance name>", "<new database name>", "<database password>", "<database backup filename>")
    If _ins.IsDone = False Then _ins.ShowDialog()
    If _ins.IsRestart = True Then
        Application.Exit()
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: If you want to convert the return statement as well, use `Exit Sub` if the enclosing method is a Sub (void in C#) or `Exit Function` if the enclosing method is a Function (method that returns a value).

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: No, that first if is on one line so no need for End If.

Comment: Thank you..... Could you kindly advise what could be JohnKenedy.BusinessSQLEXPRInstaller? and how to add it?